# jQuery sortable is hard to use b/c it's easy to drag outside the lines - what should I do?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery ui's sortable feature:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Works great as long as the user never drags the handle past the left border of the containing , but in practice this is easy to do - and even easier on my website, where the sortable handles have a little less whitespace to the left...

Ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: provide your code, i can't understand nothing... lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`containment`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-containment) option:

> Constrains dragging to within the
>   bounds of the specified element - can
>   be a DOM element, 'parent',
>   'document', 'window', or a jQuery
>   selector.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/ZB5Tm/1/

Notice what happens when you remove the `containment` option.